# Is something missing in Activity search?

Tags: activities, search

In **Advanced search** I see the radio buttons *With*, *Assigned to* and *Added by*. However there is no option to enter any person's name.

Is there something missing on interface level in Activities section of Advanced search?

CiviCRM 4.7.14. on Drupal (it looks the same in sandbox).

[image]

Comment: I agree, the field for putting tha name of contact is missing in the Activities search section. I need it and there is no other way how to use Advanced search and get a list of names I met with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Advanced Search, there is a whole section at the top called Basic Criteria, which has fields like Name.

On dmaster I double checked. I ran the search with just 'with, and got 92 results, i then ran the search with "d%" in the Name and it dropped to 37 Results.

Is that what you needed to know, or have i entirely missed your point?

Comment: I think you did. Quite a confusing design of interface, I'd say. Are there other ways to combine **Basic Criteria** and different sections in similar manner?

Comment: why? what would be the outcome you want? The basic criteria will be part of the search query that runs when you hit search. so if you add criteria in Basic Criteria such as Contact Type, or Name, or 'in trash' then those will apply to the search you run

Comment: Reasonable would be something like: Get all contacts that have an acitivity added by XY. This can currently be done via API and I believe this used to work in 4.2.

Comment: You are probably aware of that already but the activity search may be sufficient in some cases: /civicrm/activity/search?reset=1

Comment: @petednz-fuzion The reason of strangeness is that options (**With**, **Assigned to** and **Added by**) are far removed from the field to which they refer (i.e. Name in Basic Criteria). I have never seen something like this before. :)